# Screenshot Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow Immersive UWP

Tags: c, winapi, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to capture a specific Window in Windows 10.1. The problem is that this window is a `UWP` application. I found the class and caption of the window using `Spy++`. However, when I capture the UWP window with my Screenshot function, the output is a black bitmap. My function works for any other windows except this specific one.

The class of the UWP application is `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`

Here is my code:

```
HDC hScreenDC = GetWindowDC(ProgramData->TargetWnd);

RECT Rect = {0};
GetWindowRect(ProgramData->TargetWnd, &Rect);

INT Width  = Rect.right - Rect.left;
INT Height = Rect.bottom - Rect.top;

HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, Width, Height);

HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

hBitmap = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);

OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
CloseClipboard();   

DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
```

Why is the window not being captured properly and how can I capture it?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/ScreenCapture

Comment: @HansPassant Where is the actual screenshot code in that repo? I looked through all the cpp files, couldn't make it out.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutput1-duplicateoutput

Comment: Same result for me. It seems UWP not allow to be captured. Why do you need capture UWP application window?

Comment: Any application can choose [to prevent having a screenshot taken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity).